# What does this small triangular symbol at the upper-left corner of a brush preset thumbnail mean?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

[image]

I made a new triagular brush with `Edit -> Define Brush Preset`. In the Brushes panel, its thumbnail has a little triangle at the upper-left corner. The default round brush doesn't have one. What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the brush is 16bits/channel, and when you made the brush you must have been in 16bits/channel mode. If you don't want 16bit brushes, click *Image > Mode > 8 bits/channel* before making the brush.

It's almost impossible to read the numbers, but there actually is a "16" in there.

[image]

Comment: Ah, of course! I found the 16 easy enough to read, but could only think of obviously incorrect things like ‘it’s the 16th preset/swatch’. ‍♂️